# SDL/Pygame failing to load PNG images with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, sdl, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm running Python 3.1 on Windows and I'm trying to distribute my Pygame script as an executable via cx_Freeze. Right now it seems to be working except that the exe build can't load any of my images:

```
Cannot load image: C:\path\to\build\exe.win32-3.1\resources\image.png
File is not a Windows BMP file
```

Googling has revealed that this happens when the SDL imaging library doesn't get included correctly. However, `SDL_image.dll` and `libpng12-0.dll` are both put by cx_Freeze into my build directory, so it seems to me like everything should be fine. Why wouldn't it be able to load PNG images?

EDIT: I "solved" this problem by porting my script to Python 2.6 and using py2exe instead since it had some functionality anyway that I needed.

Comment: does it works before freezing?. what happens if you convert your file to .bmp?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine before freezing. If I convert the images to .bmp they load fine, but I would much rather have the option of using .png if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test by inserting some python code to display one message indicating that the libraries have loaded and another message to indicate that their loading resulted in an error.

```
try:
   import SDL_image
   print "Loaded SDL_image"
except:
   print "Failed to import SDL_image"

try:
   import libpng
   print "Loaded libpng"
except:
   print "Failed to import libpng"
```

Comment: I'm not using cx_freeze anymore (see the edit above) but I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue many times, but I found out how to deal with it.

**The problem** 
It seems that there is a conflict between two possible dependencies. The file `jpeg.dll` is included from the JRE (on Windows, something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\`), but it is the wrong one. It should be included from the Pygame directory, located within your Python installation, at `C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\pygame\`. Don't know why cx_Freeze prefers the one from the JRE, though…

**How to fix it?**
It is quite easy. Just copy the correct file (the one from Pygame) to the directory in which you execute the cx_Freeze script. When you will start it, the script will look in the current directory first, and will find the correct `jpeg.dll`. Your executable should be able to import PNG images now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pillow` instead of `pygame.image.load` to load images.

First, install the pillow package, then use the following function to load images

```
 from PIL import Image
    
 def loadImage(img_path):
     img = Image.open(img_path)
     img = img.convert("RGBA")
     return pygame.image.fromstring(img.tobytes(), img.size, "RGBA")
```